# Is there any European politics study related to the effectiveness of pets usage in political campaigning?

Tags: europe, campaigning

Romania is preparing for the Presidential elections and [one of members of a party posted a photo with that of the party president holding a cat](https://www.libertatea.ro/stiri/pisici-in-campania-electorala-dan-barna-pozat-cu-o-felina-in-brate-2787598) (original in Romanian, the following quote was written in English):

> (..) "I’m a simple person, I see cat, I vote." (..)

Some argued that this is a childish gesture, but intuitively this should help since [it seems to be effective in marketing and advertising campaigns](https://www.professorshouse.com/its-smart-to-use-pets-in-marketing-and-advertising-campaigns/).

I thought of trying to find how pets are used in other countries political spheres.

[Many US Democratic candidates rely on four-leg companions](https://qz.com/1552748/meet-the-dogs-of-the-2020-presidential-race/) and [virtually all recent US presidents had a dog](https://www.politico.eu/article/pooches-politicians-and-other-animals-vladimir-putin-jean-claude-juncker-pandas-barack-obama/). Also Nixon seems [to had a significant advantage due to his dog](https://theconversation.com/politics-on-four-legs-presidents-and-their-pets-17306).

I am curious if there is any study related to pets usage in European politics, let's say in the last 30 years.

**Question:** Is there any European politics study related to the effectiveness of pets usage in political campaigning?

Comment: Apparently Putin also [likes dogs](https://www.politico.eu/article/pooches-politicians-and-other-animals-vladimir-putin-jean-claude-juncker-pandas-barack-obama/), although for him probably doesn't matter in terms of elections. Apparently he did use one to stress out Merkel in a meeting though.

Comment: A lot of the Democrats running for President have gotten some media attention about their dogs/cats.